# how to create proper html tags in json

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a json object which looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "id_1636844335636",
    "title": "Emmy",
    "start": "2021-11-09",
    "end": "2021-11-10",
    "description": "<img class=\"img-fluid\" src=\"data\/uploads\/content_media_6190432d1512a.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"196\" height=\"130\" \/>",
    "allDay": true,
    "order": 1
}
```

When reading the json data, i got a js error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

When i replace the `\"` with `'` in the description, everything is fine.

```
// no error when changing to this:
"description": "<img class='img-fluid' src='data\/uploads\/content_media_6190432d1512a.jpg' alt='' width=\"196\" height='130' \/>",
```

I use these jsons in fullcalendar script. i really dont know why the escaping characters`\"` causing a problem. Is the syntax in the json wrong somehow?

By the way: this is how json is create by php:

```
$file = 'data/'.$id.'.json';
$jsonData = json_encode($array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($file, $jsonData);
```

**Update**: this is part of the Fullcalendar script which reads the json data:

```
 events: [
        
            <?php
                        
            $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('data/rooster/')); // read all files from all the years dirs
            $roosterfiles = []; 
            foreach ($rii as $roosterfile) {
                if ($roosterfile->isDir()){ 
                    continue;
                }
                $roosterfiles[] = $roosterfile->getPathname(); 
            }
            
            
            //$roosterfiles = glob('data/rooster/2021/*.json'); // all roosterfiles in events folder
            
            foreach($roosterfiles as $roosterfile) {
                $objs[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($roosterfile), true); // decode to php assoc array              
            }
            
            foreach($objs as $key => $val) {                
            ?>
            {
                // Eventdata
                id: "<?php echo $val['id']; ?>",                            // id               
                groupId: "<?php echo $val['groupId']; ?>",                  // groupId integer only! 
                category: "<?php echo $val['category']; ?>",                // category
                title: "<?php echo $val['title']; ?>",                      // title
                backgroundColor: "<?php echo $val['backgroundColor']; ?>",  // bg color
                textColor: "<?php echo $val['textColor']; ?>",              // textcolor    
                start: "<?php echo $val['start']; ?>",                      // start  
                end: "<?php echo $val['end']; ?>",                          // end
                description: "<?php echo $val['description']; ?>",          // description
                url: "<?php echo $val['url']; ?>",                          // url
                borderColor: "<?php echo $val['backgroundColor']; ?>",      // optional; same color as background
                allDay: "<?php echo $val['allDay']; ?>",                    // default all day event
                order: "<?php echo $val['order']; ?>",                      // order by category                
            },              
                                
            <?php   
            } // end foreach                 
                
            ?>

        
         
        
        ],
```

Comment: You don't need to escape forward-slashes in JSON strings (only in RegExps). So change `data\/uploads\/` to `data/uploads/`.

Comment: You need to show us your code that "reads the JSON data".

Comment: You aren't correctly rendering your PHP strings into JSON strings btw. You're also potentially opening yourself up to XSS attacks (as a malicious JS script or code could go through PHP and be rendered into the user's page, and then steal cookies, etc).